Grouping rows in a Pandas dataframe based on one column, sorting based on a second column, and selecting elements in a third column (not pivoting)
I have a dataframe, df_prices, which contain information about a set of objects. AI have 3 columns: 'uid', 'date' and 'price', where 'uid' has multiple (repeated) entries:
df_prices
index   uid date        price 
0       123 02-02-2000  11100
1       123 01-01-2000  22200
2       123 03-03-2000  44000
3       123 04-04-2000  66000
4       456 03-03-2000  77700
5       456 02-02-2000  88800
6       456 04-04-2000  66600
...     ... ...         ...
98      987 01-01-2005  12300
99      987 04-04-2005  45600
100     987 05-05-2005  78900

I want to group the dataframe based on the 'uid' column, then sort each group based on 'date' column, and extract the 'price' on the "oldest" date.
The result will saved in another dataframe with only 'uid' (with no duplicated entries) and 'price' which contains the oldest price.
So, the needed result should be:
df_oldest_prices
index   uid   price 
0       123   22200
1       456   88800
...     ...  ...     
40      987   12300

I have managed to achieve the result with an iterrows loop:
uids = df_prices['uid']

uids_unique = list(set(uids))

df_oldest_prices['uid'] = uids_unique

df_oldest_prices['price'] = np.nan


for index, row in df_oldest_prices.iterrows():
    uid = row['uid']
    group = df_prices.loc[df_prices['uid']==uid]
    groupsorted = group.sort_values('date')
    firstrow = groupsorted.iloc[0]
    price = firstrow['price']
    df_oldest_prices.at[index, 'price'] = price

However, I need a vectorized pandas code, for optimized speed.
I have carefully checked all the questions/answers in this question, however none of them is suitable for my task. In particular, in my task I can not use a pivot, because I don't need aggregated data. I need to sort data in 'date', and then select a single element in the 'price' column, the one on the same row as the oldest sorted date. So, no aggregation, no pivoting.

Looks like a pivot by one column Q/A 10 here

You might want to transform your two inputs into a [mre] (i.e. no ...) and provide the exact expected output to ensure we correctly understood your question.

@mozway I have added the exact expected output. About the MRE, I have improved the input dataframes; but I don't have a good example of how to even try to compute the expected output...

@mozway I have added the code to obtain the EEO, but using iterrows. So now the question is how to obtain the result in a more efficient way

@Fabio can you try df_characteristics['price'] = df_characteristics['uid'].map(df_price['price'].drop_duplicates('uid').set_index('uid')['price'])?

@mozway thanks for your help! I tried your code, it returns an error:
----> 1 df_characteristics['price'] = df_characteristics['uid'].map(df_prices['price'].drop_duplicates('uid').set_index('uid')['price'])
TypeError: Series.drop_duplicates() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

by the way, I had to correct my code with iterrows(), it was not updating the dataframe, so the result was full of NaNs. Now with "df.at[index, col] = val" it works!
